# Is JMeter Dashboard not able to create chart with small users?

Tags: java, performance, jmeter, dashboard

First of all, I've been only using JMeter for few days so excuse my ignorance. Recently I'm creating dashboard for each test runs.

Here's my thread group set up..

[image]

```
sh jmeter  -n -t ./sample_jmeter.jmx -l ./sample_jmeter.jtl -e -o ./sample_dashboard
```

By running this command, jmeter generates dashboard apparently. However chart only visible when I run with 200+ virtual users. When I'm dealing with 20 or 50 users graphic charts from dashboard looks weird. (I didn't change any of the properties from JMeter.)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

1. Test duration of 30 seconds
2. Dashboard default granularity of 1 minute

If you want to see "charts" rather than "dots" you need to:

- either increase the duration of your test to be at least 2 minutes
- or decrease the granularity to i.e. 1 second, the relevant setting is `jmeter.reportgenerator.overall_granularity` and you can set it i.e. in *user.properties* file:

  ```
   jmeter.reportgenerator.overall_granularity=1000
  ```

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [HTML Reporting Dashboard - General Settings](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#configuration_general)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [JMeter Properties Reference - Reporting Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#reporting)